SPARQL Federated Queries to Wikidata from nobelprize times out
I'm trying to do a SPARQL federated query from nobelprize endpoint to Wikidata endpoint, but it returns a 502 Proxy Error.
The code:
SELECT * WHERE {
SERVICE <https://query.wikidata.org/sparql> {
    ?j ?k ?l 
  }
} LIMIT 10

Things I've tried:

I've tried to do the opposite (from Wikidata to nobelprize), but it also returns another error:

SPARQL-QUERY: queryStr=select * where {
SERVICE <https://data.nobelprize.org/store/sparql/> {
    ?j ?k ?l 
  }
} LIMIT 10


I've tried to do a federated query from Wikidata to DBpedia (endpoint: http://dbpedia.org/sparql) and to Europeana (endpoint: http://sparql.europeana.eu/), both work but I need to access nobelprize.

Querying DBpedia and works:
SELECT *
WHERE {
  SERVICE <http://dbpedia.org/sparql>{
  SELECT *
  WHERE{                          
    ?s ?p ?o
  }
  LIMIT 10
}

Querying Europeana and works:
SELECT *
WHERE {
   SERVICE <http://sparql.europeana.eu/>{
   SELECT *
   WHERE{                          
     ?s ?p ?o
   }
   LIMIT 10
  }  
}


I've tried to use a local server (Jena), and I can query "wikidata" and "nobelprize" individually, but when entering a federated query (from either endpoint), the aforementioned errors appear.


why can't you consume both endpoints in the Jena Fuseki server locally then? Also, what kind of real query do you want to run in the end?

Moreover, from the public Wikidata endpoint only a whitelist of remote URLs work because of licensing: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_federation_input

the issue with a query to Wikidata in your current form I see is that you don't pass the LIMIT into the SERVICE clause. That means, it might try to fetch all the billions of triples of Wikidata and afterwards to the LIMIT locally. In addition ,they also might block outgoing request via SERVICE clause, I don't know how setup the endpoint with what kind of restrictions. But even that query fails, select * where {   SERVICE <https://query.wikidata.org/sparql> {     VALUES ?s {1}   } } - so I doubt it works from their end. Mayeb the server is busy

my suggestion: download the Nobel Prize Dataset dump from here, load into Fuseki, then do an efficient federated query which does select some data from the local dataset and enrich it with Wikidata via SERVICE clause

Thanks for the suggestion. I had to download the dataset from https://www.ida.liu.se/research/semanticweb/events/SemWebCourse2018/nobelprize.nt but it worked perfectly

I could solve the problem thanks to @UninformedUser's comment:

download the Nobel Prize Dataset dump from here, load into Fuseki, then do an efficient federated query which does select some data from the local dataset and enrich it with Wikidata via SERVICE clause

P.S., I had to download the dataset from https://www.ida.liu.se/research/semanticweb/events/SemWebCourse2018/nobelprize.nt
It worked perfectly.
